# Magento Checkout top link change link path

Tags: checkout, url

The top links for Magento include the following

My Account  My Wishlist Checkout and Login

When Checkout is clicked, it takes you to Checkout page.

I would like it when Checkout is clicked, it takes you to My Cart or the Shopping Cart page.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Matt,

Magento top link is coming from class `Mage_Checkout_Block_Links` on function

`addCheckoutLink()`.

- **You need rewrite this class**

`<global>
        ...
        <blocks>
            <checkout>
            <rewrite>
                <links>Amit_CustomCheckout_Block_Checkout_Link</links>
            </rewrite>
            </checkout>
        </blocks>
        ...
        </global>`

- **and need to modify code of addCheckoutLink();**

> public function addCheckoutLink()
>       {
>           if (!$this->helper('checkout')->canOnepageCheckout()) {
>               return $this;
>           }
>
> ```
>     $parentBlock = $this->getParentBlock();
>     if ($parentBlock && Mage::helper('core')->isModuleOutputEnabled('Mage_Checkout')) {
>         $text = $this->__('Checkout');
>
>   $url='CustomUrl'; // with format routeridenfier/controller/Action
>         $parentBlock->addLink(
>             $text, $url, $text,
>             true, array('_secure' => true), 60, null,
>             'class="top-link-checkout"'
>         );
>     }
>     return $this;
> }
> ```

Comment: for someone well versed in magento and its workings, this may seem easy, however i need to know what files to edit to achieve this. I really appreciate your answering the question. a really detailed step by step would be great! Sorry , i am learning every day!